# Unreal Development Kit - What is a good method for accessing a relational database file?

Tags: udk, unreal

I'd like to use a SQL Express file or something similar for a UDK demo.

Is there a standard method for accessing data in a local relational database file?

I understand that the best method may involve creating a class library and using the DLLBind feature, but I'm still a bit unclear on how to pass data to controls in the UI (I'd like to populate dropdowns and such with records from the database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of UDK, but Google turns up http://forums.epicgames.com/showthread.php?t=726137 as an example. (and yes, you should use SQLite for this)